# Eclipse Java | Android stopped working just after update

Tags: java, android, eclipse

After I updated eclipse (just now) the Java parser stopped working and it got like this (as seen in the images). When I try to run the activities I get an alert

> "The selection cannot be launched, and there are no recent launches."

http://www.imagebam.com/image/3c7a76340551624
http://www.imagebam.com/image/417324340551622

I just found this too:

http://www.imagebam.com/image/c25d04340552586

Comment: Creative the h ttp. I know this is lame, but some of these errors went away because of a rouge process. So, restart the stuff.

Comment: Surely you rebooted and cleaned before creating an account on Stackoverflow and posting a question?

Comment: @323go of course... I don't really understand why this is happening